# Migrating MySQL databases from files only

Tags: mysql, macos

On a fresh install of MySQL on Mavericks (via Homebrew if that matters) how can I take database files from a back up and migrate them to /usr/local/var/mysql in the new instance? I have a directory for each database and one huge ibdata1 file.

If I move them by a simple file transfer, start the new instance and log in, each database is there however no data is present when I check a table.

Comment: It _might_ work if the versions are exactly alike, but a dump with something like `xtrabackup` is for more likely to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work if keeping or upgrading server version. Make sure ownership and permissions are correct. Then run mysql_upgrade which will adjust the files.